# Seperated Django frontend and Django backend?

Tags: django

So I am creating my first django project for work and I think I am getting familar with it.

I designed my views and URLs strongly oriented to REST principles. But since I render html and use forms to manipulate data, it is actually not REST in terms of pushing or pulling data.

I have actually no desire to create a separated frontend in a different framework running at a different adress.

But I wondered if it would be a reasonable idea to create an app frontend in my project and make all the other apps serve and receive json to make them restfull. Then I could use the frontend app to render the templates and query the data from the other endpoints.

But maybe it's a stupid idea for reasons I don't see or I am unsure about.

Comment: This is totally a personal choice, I had a Django app In which I had HTML templates, REST api and Channels implemented. I would advise you to stick to RESTful architecture if and only if the application is going to scale to multiple devices (Android/iOS). Otherwise it is completely optional and a personal choice :)

Comment: You are talking about native ios/android apps instead of webpage?

Comment: Yes, you should prefer RESTful architecture if you intend to use it as a backend for native Android/iOS application

Comment: Hmm digging into the topic of web engineering one gets the feeling that rest for everything is the state of the art.